# lwIP - Difference between tcp_alloc and tcp_new

Tags: lwip

I am using the lwIP library (version 1.4.1) with raw API.

What is the difference between `tcp_alloc()` and `tcp_new()` functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tcp_alloc is an internal function that's only meant for use within the lwIP library. tcp_new is part of lwIP's public API; it creates a new connection identifier (PCB).